# Windows 2003 - lock screen without screen saver

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows

Back to Windows NT 4.0 there where a screen saver named "Windows logon". It mimic the usual logon screen (but the dialogue box moved randomly on the screen to avoid some burning process). I think it was also available with Windows 2000.

On Windows 2003 it is not longer available.

Is there a way to:
 1. lock a session after a defined timeout
 2. have some sort of logon screen displayed as screensaver
 3. extra: if it could skip the ctrl+shift+del step, this will be cool (so just to type the password then enter)

As a last resort I could use a screen capture of the logon screen, displayed by a screen saver.

Comment: This screensaver still exists, just the image was replaced by a windows logo.

Comment: And all the other options are available. The three finger salute can be disabled through policies.

Answer (score 4):

You could just blank the screen using the power saving options and get the server to be locked this way.

Also if the "Windows Logon" screensaver is really gone from Server 2003, consider simply copying the Logon.scr file from the %windir%\system32 directory of an XP machine. The SCRs are just disguised executables and a screen saver file from XP without any major dependencies should work well on Server 2003.

BTW: there is a "Do not Require users to press Ctrl+Alt+Delete" policy setting - you should not be prompted for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Del</kbd> upon enabling it.

Comment: We don't want to blank the screen: we want the logon dialog. This is because we very often switch from one machine to anoter, either with virtual machines, either with KVM switch. And every time we have a blank screen, we have to move the mouse or type a key to know if this is the right computer).

Comment: Windows XP doesn't have the desired screen saver. So I can't copy from it :) And I don't have any Windows 2000 handy, and Google didn't lead me to anywhere of value for that. But I'll remember this advice.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'm missing something here but it looks to me that in W2K3 this does exist.

1. Set the screensaver to any of the three default screensavers available (the Windows 2003 screensaver "flies" the Windows 2003 logo around the screen)
2. Set the wait time to be the amount of time you want Windows to wait (idle time) before invoking the screensaver
3. Check the option "On resume, password protect"

Does this not give you what you're looking for? I just tested this from an RDP session to a W2K3 server and it did exactly what you've described as not being available.

Comment: Sorry, but no. We don't want anything other than the logon dialog, even a fake one. So now I put a screenshot of the real one :) Dummy but efficient.